# Printing listview in asp.net with css, using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css, printing

It is not using the css class when printing
but I see the css class when using the program

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function printDiv() {
            var divToPrint = document.getElementById('DivIdToPrint');
            var newWin = window.open('', 'Print-Window');

            //newWin.document.open();
            newWin.document.write('<html><body onload="window.print()">' + divToPrint.innerHTML + '</body></html>');
            newWin.document.close();
            setTimeout(function() { newWin.close(); }, 10);
        }

    </script>



 <div id="DivIdToPrint" class="ListadoLicencias">
          <asp:Listview>
      </div>

                 <br />
  <asp:Button runat="server" ID="cmdImprimir" Text="Imprimir" OnClientClick="printDiv();"  />
```

Comment: I don't understand. What is the problem? `<asp:Listview>` does nothing by the way.

Comment: I know it was just to tell that I've a listview there

The problem is that I have the class "ListadoLicencias", and it's not showing on the print preview.. I'll attach some images

Comment: please check this link http://clip2net.com/s/4M2P0m
up is the listview showing with the css, down is the print preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that `innerHTML` just does what it says: It takes the **inner** HTML. You would need to do something like

```
newWin.document.write(
    '<html><body><div id="DivIdToPrint" class="ListadoLicencias">'
        + divToPrint.innerHTML
        + '</div></body></html>'
);
```

or take the `innerHTML` from the parent element.

To have your stylesheets applied, you'll have to extend the HTML you write within your popup function to

```
<html><head><link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet"/></head><!-- ... --></html>
```

Comment: @hptech, Well, is there any `<link rel="stylesheet"/>` in the generated HTML? Where should the styles for the class come from?